# Is it possible to disable GCM service for some time?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I have an application where I'm using GCM and I want to receive notifications only when app is closed, but when it's foreground don't receive them.

So is there some functionality to disable `GcmListenerService` for a while?

Comment: I don't know if there is a GCM-specific solution, but you can always use `PacakgeManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`.

Comment: @KOrest Did u get any proper solution for this?

Comment: @manini No, I did it as suggested skipping message when foreground

Answer (score 2):

You do this wrong way. It is irrelevant really when your app will receive GCM message. In your case it's more important when it react to it. So instead of disabling your application component, I'd simply put some logic that would either ignore messages under certain conditions (like it's in foreground) or handle them differently in that case. That, for me, looks like better way than turning your app completely deaf.

Comment: Isn't it needless to use resources if we are not using it?

Comment: There will be not that much of savings - the GCM message will be delivered to your device - you will just not pick it up. From my perspective is simpler to just drop the message (so all the logic is in my code) once the receiver picks it, than rely on PackageManager.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to track if your app is in foreground / background using Activity Life cycle callback.

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application
{
    private static int  sRunningActivityCount   = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks(){
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity)
        {
            sRunningActivityCount++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity)
        {
            sRunningActivityCount--;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity)
        {

        }
    });
    }

public static boolean isAppBackground()
{
    return sRunningActivityCount == 0;
}

public static boolean isAppForeground()
{
    return sRunningActivityCount != 0;
}
```

}

You can use the following to enable/disable receiving GCM notifications:

```
public void setNotifications(boolean enabled)
{
    mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(mContext, YourGcmListenerService.class), enabled ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED
            : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourGcmListenerService.class);
    if (enabled)
    {
        mContext.startService(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        mContext.stopService(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel with your BaseClass here because since API14 there're [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)

Comment: Agree with you on this, will update my answer accordingly.